# JSON not transferring "+" character to CGI script

Tags: javascript, python, json, escaping, cgi

I am currently working on a personal project, where I have to deal with some chemical formulas;

I have a form with JavaScript where I enter these formulas; The formulas are entered in a LaTeX-like style for super- en subscript.

An example formula can be found below:

`Fe^{3+}`

When I use JavaScript to read the form and `console.log();` the formula is working as expected.
However if I send the formula to the back-end (Python with CGI), the `+` character seems to have disappeared and been replaced with a space.

I thought it had something to do with escaping the character, since parts of the formula look a lot like regex's, but after looking around, I couldn't find anything that would suggest that I had to escape the `+` character.

And now I have absolutely no idea how to resolve this... I could use a different character and replace it on the back-end but that seems like it is not the optimal solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most important question: **How did you invoke the CGI script?**

With HTTP GET or HTTP POST?

If you're using HTTP POST and the data was being transferred in the HTTP Data portion, then you don't need to escape the "+" sign.

But if you're using HTTP GET, then the "+" sign will first be translated according to URL encoding standard (thus, "+" becomes a space), before transferred to the CGI script.

So in the latter scenario, you *need* to escape the "+" sign (and other 'special' characters such as "%" and "?").

Comment: I hadn't thought about that yet...
But yes I am using HTTP get, and your suggestion fixed the problem!
I am using the javascript `encodeURIComponent()` function.